React Native Reanimated Carousel - Card With Rotate Animation
I want to achieve a carousel that have this animation using React Native Reanimated Carousel:
https://i.sstatic.net/K8VtubGy.gif
As you may see from the gif, when we scroll to half way:

the second card rotates from -15deg to 0deg, as it becomes the first card visible.
the third card rotates from 0deg to -15deg, as it becomes the second card visible.

I have created a minium code example try to repulicate the animation:
I have created currentIndex to keep track of selected index, and using Math.round to determine if we are swipe halfway already.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import Animated, { useAnimatedStyle, interpolate, useSharedValue, withTiming } from 'react-native-reanimated';
import Carousel from "react-native-reanimated-carousel";

export default function App() {
    const data = ['#00ff00', '#ff00ff', '#0000ff'];
    const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

    const CardItem = ({ item, index, animationValue }) => {
        const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
            const rotate = interpolate(
                index,
                [currentIndex, currentIndex + 1],
                [0, -15]
            );

            return {
                transform: [
                    { rotate: `${rotate}deg` },
                ],
            };
        });
      
        return (
            <Animated.View style={[animatedStyle, { backgroundColor: item, height: 200, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }]}>
                <Text>{index}</Text>
            </Animated.View>
        );
      };

    return (
        <View style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', overflow: 'visible' }}>
            <Carousel
                enabled
                loop
                data={data}
                width={width - 20}
                height={300}
                pagingEnabled={true}
                mode={'horizontal-stack'}
                modeConfig={{
                    showLength: 2
                }}
                style={{
                    alignSelf: 'center'
                }}
                onProgressChange={(offset, progress) => {
                    setCurrentIndex(Math.round(progress));
                }}
                renderItem={({ item, index, animationValue }) => {
                    return (
                        <CardItem item={item} index={index} animationValue={animationValue} />
                    )
                }} />
        </View>
    );
}

However it not work as expected:
https://i.sstatic.net/2fZJjPOM.gif
I'm new to React Native Reanimated and React Native Reanimated Carousel, how to achieve the animation in the first gif correctly?
